# Can I access and run from my local machine a SSH hosted Google Cloud VM Ubuntu python file?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, kivy

I am trying to store python scripts on a VM Ubuntu instance on Google Cloud, where I can access it from my VSCode python IDE locally or on Android Kivy app. I want to say something like this:

```
1) Locally or on Android Kivy app: %run File.py
2) Google Cloud: runs File.py
3) Locally or on Android Kivy app: results from run File.py are displayed.
```

Is this something that can be easily done? I am not really sure where to start.

Comment: Yes, check out the Remote SSH extension for VS Code.

Comment: This [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) might be useful

Comment: vscode is like the god of every editors this thing has anything for everything